# R reshape a vector into multiple columns

Tags: r, vector, matrix, reshape, reshape2

Let's say I have a vector in R as follows:

```
d<-seq(1,100)
```

I want to reshape this vector into a 10x10 matrix, so that I will have this data instead:

```
[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  ..  [,10]   
  1      2    3   ..   10
  11    12   13   ..   20
  21    22   23   ..   30
  ..
  91    92   93    ..  100
```

I tried to use reshape function, but it didn't work.  Can someone help please?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do

```
dim(d) <- c(10, 10)
d <- t(d)
```

or

```
d <- matrix(d, nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a predifined list to a matrix (e.g. a 5*4 matrix), do

```
yourMatrix <- matrix(unlist(yourList), nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
```

It is worth noting that the matrix is created by columns, which means your data will be **filled into the matrix by columns**. So, if you want to the matrix created by rows, simply using ***t()***, such as

```
yourMatrix <- matrix(unlist(yourList), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)  # exchanges the cols and rows
yourMatrix <- t(yourMatrix)  # matrix transpose
```